# Aggregating angular libraries into a meta library and re-exporting

Tags: angular, npm, angular-library

I have built a number of libraries in an Angular 9 project using ng-packagr. Each library is concise and contains services/components/modules for a larger system and yet can be used alone. I wish these libraries to be installable individually through npm. I also wish to have one library that consolidates them all. I know I can consolidate the code from these libraries into one library/package, but I would rather keep them separate. Would it be frowned upon to create a manager library (library of libraries) that aggregates the smaller libraries, re-exports them, therby acting as a single entry point?